# ORDER BY condition for a group of rows

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, codeigniter-3

Here i want to get results of similar `number` rows together that means one after another and each row will be having different counts of data and the rows which have higher count should come first,here is my code

```
public function get_all_mostly_entered_numbers($limit,$offset)
{

    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT *, SUM(quantity) AS MOST_FREQUENT
         FROM datas
         WHERE date_status=1
         GROUP BY number,type
         ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 200");

    return $query->result();
}
```

the result is coming like this

```
type        number       count
sup          555         280
sup          000         245
sup          777         235
sup          888         235
bo           000         40
bo           777         30
bo           888         25
bo           555         10
```

i want my result to be like this

```
type        number       count
sup          555         280
bo           555         10
sup          000         245
bo           000         40
sup          777         235
bo           777         30
sup          888         235
bo           888         25
```

Comment: This is going to be tough to do without analytic functions or session variables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Now i think you got what i meaned

Comment: Is the ordering always determined by the `sup` value?  Also, are `bo` and `sup` the only two types?

Comment: No other types are also there and the ordering is not always determined by `sup` value.which value is having higher sum depends on that

Comment: Then I don't see an easy way to do this with MySQL.

Comment: can we give `order by` condition to similar fetched numbers like similar numbers in a group

Comment: In your example data, the column `number` appears to come out as varchar and sum (`quantity`) appears in the results as 'count' rather than 'MOST_FREQUENT'. Could you give us a more meaningful example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to the sample provided

You could use a join of the result with the max  result and order based  ( in th sample there a max_val colum  for better understand the result)

```
 select T.number, max(T.MOST_FREQUENT) max_val, W.MOST_FREQUENT, W.Type
  from (

  SELECT *, SUM(quantity) AS MOST_FREQUENT
       FROM datas
       WHERE date_status=1
       GROUP BY number,type
       ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 200 ) T 
  INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, SUM(quantity) AS MOST_FREQUENT
           FROM datas
           WHERE date_status=1
           GROUP BY number,type
           ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 200
  ) W ON T.number = W.number 
  group by T.number, , W.MOST_FREQUENT, W.Type
  ORDER BY  max(T.MOST_FREQUENT)  DESC
           , (max(T.MOST_FREQUENT)=W.MOST_FREQUENT) DESC
           ,  W.MOST_FREQUENT
           , W.Type
```

You can not show max_val  simply select from the result (ordered ) only the column you need

And for avoid the wrong sequence with same max_row you could try

```
select T.number, max(T.MOST_FREQUENT) max_val, W.MOST_FREQUENT, W.Type
  from (

  SELECT *, SUM(quantity) AS MOST_FREQUENT
       FROM datas
       WHERE date_status=1
       GROUP BY number,type
       ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 200 ) T 
  INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, SUM(quantity) AS MOST_FREQUENT
           FROM datas
           WHERE date_status=1
           GROUP BY number,type
           ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 200
  ) W ON T.number = W.number 
  group by T.number, , W.MOST_FREQUENT, W.Type
  ORDER BY  concat(lpad(max(T.MOST_FREQUENT), 10, '0'), T.number)  DESC
           , (concat(max(T.MOST_FREQUENT, T.number))= concat(W.MOST_FREQUENT, T.number)) DESC
           ,  W.MOST_FREQUENT
           , W.Type
```

Comment: getting error like this `Reference 'max_val' not supported (reference to group function)`

Comment: please check my answer which i posted

Comment: for the `max_ref`  ref  is simple  .. reference change  .. answer  updated ..  hope this return the right result

Comment: please go  through my answer and the details,still my result looks like in the result which i gave in my answer

Comment: now by using this the entire result looks changed.can we use like this `the same numbers of same types should come together and should show depends on the maximum count

Comment: answer updated  preventing the different order by string an number .. left me know  ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166137/discussion-between-user-777-and-scaisedge).

Comment: now again result came like the one which i posted in my answer

Comment: answer updated  .. using T.number in concat instead of type

Comment: you are welcome ..   ..in the previous answer  I had confused the columns

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query=$this->db->query("SELECT *,T.number, max(T.MOST_FREQUENT), W.MOST_FREQUENT, W.Type
   from (

   SELECT *, SUM(quantity) AS MOST_FREQUENT
   FROM datas
   WHERE date_status=1
   GROUP BY number,type
   ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 200 ) T 
   INNER JOIN (
   SELECT *, SUM(quantity) AS MOST_FREQUENT
       FROM datas
       WHERE date_status=1
       GROUP BY number,type
       ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC LIMIT 200
         ) W ON T.number = W.number 
           group by T.number, W.MOST_FREQUENT, W.Type
           ORDER BY  max(T.MOST_FREQUENT)  DESC
           , (max(T.MOST_FREQUENT)=W.MOST_FREQUENT) DESC
           ,  W.MOST_FREQUENT
           , W.Type");

 return $query->result();
```

i changed the code like this am getting result like this

```
 type        number       count
sup          555         280
bo           555         10
sup          000         245
bo           000         40
sup          777         235
sup          888         235
bo           777         30
bo           888         25
```

if two numbers have same count that two numbers are coming one after another rather than picking same numbers